# Поиск индекса элемента List по значению

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Есть `List<Student>` students со свойствами:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Есть переменная

```
string text;
```

Нужно найти индекс List-а students такого, что свойство Name совпадало со строкой text (Name == text), используя LINQ и лямбда выражения.

Comment: Переставьте галку на вариант @Андрей NOP - он лучше так как не содержит двойного поиска. А мой вариант хоть и был первым - был написан глубокой ночью и не самый оптимальный.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В классе `List` есть специальный метод [`FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx), принимающий предикат. В качестве предиката можно передать лямбда выражение. Хоть здесь и не используются методы Linq, но этот способ более эффективен (один проход по списку):

```
var students = new List<Student>()
{
    new Student { Id = 0, Name = "Ivan" },
    new Student { Id = 1, Name = "Petr" },
    new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Oleg" },
};
var needle = "petr";
int index = students.FindIndex(s =>
    string.Equals(s.Name, needle, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine(index);
```

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
    {
        new Student{Id = 0, Name = "Ivan"},
        new Student{Id = 1, Name = "Petr"},
        new Student{Id = 2, Name = "Oleg"},
    };
    var needle = "petr";
    var elem = students.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Name, needle, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    var index = students.IndexOf(elem);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

От linq здесь поиск студента, а раз вам нужен индекс - то здесь IndexOf

Comment: два линейных поиска?

Comment: А почему Invariant? В странах с нетривиальным collation возможны проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить расширяющий метод

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Predicate<T> condition)
{
    var i = -1;
    return list.Any(x => { i++; return condition(x); }) ? i : -1;
}
```

И искать одним запросом к списку

```
var index = students.IndexOf(x => 
            string.Equals(x.Name, needle, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```